# Cross-origin in local filesystem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, html5-canvas

Really need help here and soon. Trying to make a little javascript program to help someone with a presentation. Believe it or not, his computer will practically die from MS Power Point and Libre Office because the ppt is just that huge.

I've been programming a sample with a good number of pages to work with Chrome, and it is made in a way so that the page is divided in half where on one side is a `canvas` with the main presentation, and on the other is a smaller `canvas` that after every transition displays a copy of the first `canvas` (through `ctx2.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);`).

Now, first time running this I of course come across the problem of `CORS` errors. I give each image `.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"`, and I run Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`. This gets things working on my computers (both Win10 Home and Ubuntu 16.04), but once I send my friend this package and he runs it with `--allow-file-access-from-files`, it gives that `CORS` error.

```
Access to image at 'file:///D:/.../image2.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know many would say upload it to a server, but we cannot guarantee Internet connection at where he's going, hence the "local package". His Chrome is up to date (64.0.3282.186 Official Build 64-bit), as is mine (Win10 same numbers but 32-bit, Ubuntu 56.0.2924.87 64-bit). What other options can I use to bypass the `CORS` security? Preferably as command-line switches to put in a `bat` file or something within the `html` file, and not having him turn his laptop into a web server or compiling something.

Edit: By Kosh Very's request, here's the "Minimalist".

```js
var canvas1;
var canvas2;
var ctx1;
var ctx2;
var img = [];

 onload = function()
 {
  canvas1 = document.getElementById("display1");
  ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
  canvas2 = document.getElementById("display2");
  ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
  img[0] = new Image();
  img[0].crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img[0].onload = function()
  {
   ctx1.drawImage(img[0],320-(img[0].width/2),240-(img[0].height/2));
   ctx2.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);
  }
  img[0].src = "image2.png";
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="display1" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
<canvas id="display2" width="640px" height="480px"></canvas>
```

Copy that to your own `html` file and provide your own `image2.png`.

Comment: Run a [local server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server) - it doesn't have to be on a remote location. It's really not that hard to set it up.

Comment: `php -S localhost:8000 index.php` where `index.php` contains `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");?>PASTE HERE HTML CONTENT`

Comment: You probably misused `canvas`. Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides But still 11 steps to go through should the case be he forgets his laptop but has it on a USB-stick. If all those steps could be one contained program-click away (or live), that would be great. @Cryptopat `php is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` @KoshVery The whole thing works on my end. How can two Chrome instances work so differently?

Comment: Option for running a simple local server: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en